# Delphi Convert GPS Coordinates for GoogleMaps

Tags: delphi, gps, coordinate

I'm getting coordinates from GPS tracker as "Lat:40 54.1434" "Lon:29 13.0226", i would like to convert this coordinates for google maps javascript api as "lat : 40.90239, lon : 29.21704". I've searched on google and found formulas+convert tool websites, i tried to understand how they converted using JavaScript but i didn't understand. Is it possible to convert using Delphi XE7 ?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your GPS tracker is giving you coordinates in degrees + [decimal minutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_and_second_of_arc).

These are quite easy to convert to plain decimal degrees, as your Google Maps API requires, by taking the first part of the coordinate and adding on the second part divided by 60.

For example, to convert `40 54.1434` to plain decimal degrees, you split up the string into `degrees = 40` and `minutes = 54.1434`, and then `decimalDegrees = degrees + minutes / 60`, which is `40 + 54.1434 / 60 = 40.90239`.

Comment: thank you so much my friend, i'm working with this from 9am in the morning and i just understand with your explanation,thank you so much.